# Hierarchy path: Find orphans (children without parents)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, tree, parser

I have *hierarchy path* values:

```
FLEET
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ COMPRESSOR - DRYER
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ VALVES
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ RESERVOIRS
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ HOSES - LINES - FITTINGS

FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS
FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS \ BLADE
FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS \ SALTER
FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS \ BROOM
FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS \ MOWER
FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS \ HITCH
FLEET \ ATTACHMENTS \ MISCELLANEOUS

["FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR" --> parent is missing]
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ BODY PANELS
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ WIPERS
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ MIRRORS
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES \ CATEGORY 1
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES \ CATEGORY 2
```

I am trying to find children that don't have parents.

For example, I want to indicate that the parent in row #16 is missing for rows #17-20.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: What do you mean "All other cells with values are parents." ? Anyway, according to my research, there is no formula for finding "children: and "parent" in excel.

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT I deleted that part -- for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-2))=1,"","Error")
```

[image]

The formula flags hierarchy paths that are orphaned (children without parents).

---

Explanation:

1) [Remove the lowest level from the hierarchy path:](https://superuser.com/questions/1547526/split-text-at-last-instance-of-character-retain-left-hand-side)

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-2)
```

2) Use `countif` to determine if the value from step #1 exists in column A.

In other words, check to see if that parent exists.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(   ...Step #1...   )=1,"","Error")
```