# Split text at last instance of character (retain left hand side)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, parser

I have *hierarchy path* values in column A of an Excel spreadsheet:

```
FLEET
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ COMPRESSOR - DRYER
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ VALVES
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ RESERVOIRS
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM \ HOSES - LINES - FITTINGS

FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ BODY PANELS
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ WIPERS
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ MIRRORS
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES \ CATEGORY 1
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES \ CATEGORY 2
```

---

I would like to split each string at the last instance of `\` and retain the left-hand side of the split string.

---

```
[null]
FLEET
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM
FLEET \ AIR SYSTEM

FLEET
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES
FLEET \ BODY EXTERIOR \ ACCESSORIES
```

---

Is it possible to do this via an Excel 2016 formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))-1),"")
```

In your comment, you indicate you want to remove the terminal `space` which is present in the original data.  You merely need to use the `TRIM` function in the formula:

```
=TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\",""))))-1),""))
```

and fill down

[image]

If your version of Excel has the `FILTERXML` and `TEXTJOIN` functions, you can use the following (which will not have a terminal `space`).

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("\",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1&"\","\","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[position()<last()-1]")),"")
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that formula returns a space at the end of the string. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @User1973 It is returning a space because that was in your specification -- everything to the left of the `\\`` and there is a space before the `\\``.  If you want to also remove that terminal space, just use the `TRIM` function around the formula.  See Edits

Comment: Thanks. I suppose, alternatively, I could use `-2` instead of `-1` to trim the space.

Comment: @User1973 You could, if you were certain that there would **always** be a space before the final backslash. Using `TRIM` (or the second formula if you can) eliminates that variation as a possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try a User Defined Function:

```
Function LPath(Target As Range) As String

LPath = Trim(Left(Target.Value, InStrRev(Target.Value, "\") - 1))

End Function
```

Place in a module using ALT F11 to enter developer and insert module, use:
LPath(A1)
If you want to keep the final "\" then remove the "-1"... if you want to keep the trailing space " " remove the trim function.

[image]